# React Native - MySQL Connection Without a Web Server?

Tags: mysql, react-native

In my company i have an inventory software with a MYSQL database that runs on a local network. With the python pyqt5 software, i can connect to it easily on dekstop computers.

I also would like to connect and do CRUD operations on mysql database with a cell phone. I am making a react native app for that.

People say, i have to use node.js. I am confused. Can't i use a library like "npm msql" to connect to database on my react native app. onPress of a react native button, i can use npm mysql method. Would this approach work?

Comment: What company is that? Do you have no cyber security department? Sorry but connecting directly from a mobile phone to a database is absolutely worst Szenario you can have

Comment: I am running a small business. It is an inventory software. It is not sensitive information. Yet you are right. It is bad practice. I am writing a backend.